# How can I perform different actions in windows batch file based on most recent version of installed program

Tags: windows, batch-file, default-programs

Some of our computers run multiple versions of Microsoft Access (97 & 2010) while others run 365. For the pcs running multiple versions, the default is set to 97. I have a batch file that is performing various tests to see if files exist, and finished by running an Access 2010 database called MWO.accdb. See below.

```
if exist c:\windows\system32\mscomct2.ocx goto step2

rem copy mscomct2 and register
cscript \\file\apps\Database\Maintenance\365\MsgBox.vbs "Preparing necessary libraries."
copy "\\file\apps\Database\Maintenance\365\mscomct2.ocx" "c:\windows\system32\"
regsvr32 /u mscomct2.ocx
regsvr32 /i mscomct2.ocx

:step2

if exist "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\MWO.lnk" goto step3

rem create shortcut on user's desktop for future use
cscript \\file\apps\Database\Maintenance\365\MsgBox.vbs "Creating shortcut on desktop & adding to start menu."
copy "\\file\apps\Database\Maintenance\MWO-INSTALL.lnk" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\MWO.lnk"
mkdir "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Maintenance"
copy "\\file\apps\Database\Maintenance\MWO-INSTALL.lnk" "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Maintenance\MWO.lnk"

:step3
\\file\apps\Database\Maintenance\365\MWO.accdb
```

Is there an easy way to test for the latest version of access, and force the file to open with it to avoid the defaulting to 97 problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
wmic product where caption="Access" get caption,version
```

(I don't have access installed, the captionstring may differ)